# How to scroll up and down for the pallete division?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click next and previous button, I want scroll up and down the div for currently active question.

Question Pallete for the reference:
[image: Question pallete screenshot]

My example code:

```
function saveNext(idValue,subtopic) {
     var aa = idValue;
       if (aa==28){

          $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(275);

      }
      if(aa==56){

       $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(550);                
      }
      if(aa==84){

       $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(825);                
      }
       if(aa==112){

       $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(1102);                
      }
      if(aa==140){

       $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(1374);                
      }
       if(aa==168){

       $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(1654);                
      }
       if(aa==196){

       $("#scrollPallete").scrollTop(1924);                
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/arunslb123/gzaLydkd/

I need exact code for vertical scroll. 
 Shall get sample code for vertical scrolling? when i click next and prev button i want to scroll up and down. Each rows having 4 questions, Totally I have 50 rows. i need to scroll up to 200 questions.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could attach a minimal example to your question.

Comment: please find my example code @RamizWachtler

Comment: If you can access the desired `target`, you can use the value of `target.offset().top` and then scroll to this position.

Comment: Can you give me sample code? It would be very useful to me.

Comment: use this [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzaLydkd/18/) as a starting point.

Comment: Shall i get your updated fiiddle with four buttons per row instead of one button per row?? @Fr0zenFyr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a sample for you, though it's not the best solution for your problem, but I think as a starting point it is more than enough.

**See snippet below (open it in "Full page" mode to see the buttons)**

```js
$('#next').click(function(e) {
  var $next = $('.number-item.selected').next('.number-item');
  var $container = $('.question-container');
  if (!$container.attr('data-scrolltop')) {
    $container.attr('data-scrolltop', $container.height());
  }
  $next.addClass('selected');
  $('.number-item.selected').first().removeClass('selected');
  if ($next.get(0).offsetTop + 12 > $container.attr('data-scrolltop')) {
    $container.animate({
      scrollTop: $next.get(0).offsetTop - 12
    }, 1000, function() {
      var currentVal = Number($container.attr('data-scrolltop'));
      var newVal = $container.get(0).scrollTop;
      $container.attr('data-scrolltop', currentVal + newVal);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.question-container {
  background: papayawhip;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
}

a.number-item {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: plum;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 4px 0;
}

a.number-item.selected {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="question-container">
  <a href="#" class="number-item selected">1</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">2</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">3</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">4</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">5</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">6</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">7</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">8</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">9</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">10</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">11</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">12</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">13</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">14</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">15</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">16</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">17</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">18</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">19</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">20</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">21</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">22</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">23</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">24</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">25</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">26</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">27</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">28</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">29</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">30</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">31</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">32</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">33</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">34</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">35</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">36</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">37</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">38</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">39</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">40</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">41</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">42</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">43</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">44</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">45</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">46</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">47</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">48</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">49</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">50</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">51</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">52</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">53</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">54</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">55</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">56</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">57</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">58</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">59</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">60</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">61</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">62</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">63</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">64</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">65</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">66</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">67</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">68</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">69</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">70</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">71</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">72</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">73</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">74</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">75</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">76</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">77</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">78</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">79</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">80</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">81</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">82</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">83</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">84</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">85</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">86</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">87</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">88</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">89</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">90</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">91</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">92</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">93</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">94</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">95</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">96</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">97</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">98</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">99</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">100</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">101</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">102</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">103</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">104</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">105</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">106</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">107</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">108</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">109</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">110</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">111</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">112</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">113</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">114</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">115</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">116</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">117</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">118</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">119</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">120</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">121</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">122</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">123</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">124</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">125</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">126</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">127</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">128</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">129</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">130</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">131</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">132</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">133</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">134</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">135</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">136</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">137</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">138</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">139</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">140</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">141</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">142</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">143</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">144</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">145</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">146</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">147</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">148</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">149</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">150</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">151</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">152</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">153</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">154</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">155</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">156</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">157</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">158</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">159</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">160</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">161</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">162</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">163</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">164</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">165</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">166</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">167</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">168</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">169</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">170</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">171</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">172</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">173</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">174</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">175</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">176</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">177</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">178</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">179</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">180</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">181</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">182</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">183</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">184</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">185</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">186</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">187</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">188</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">189</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">190</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">191</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">192</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">193</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">194</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">195</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">196</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">197</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">198</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">199</a>
  <a href="#" class="number-item">200</a>
</div>
<button id="previous">Previous</button>
<button id="next">Next</button>
```

Comment: This is very useful to me. Thank you so much for your solution.